# Text showing up in the wrong cell with css bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, vertical-alignment

I am trying to dictate that one cell in bootstrap be bottom aligned.

I tried doing this with:

```
<div class="col-md-4 column" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;'>
```

text is here

The css is:

```
.col-md-r {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
float: left;
}
```

when I apply the style setting inline, the text appears to the bottom right within the FIRST row.  This is in the FOURTH row.

If I change the position:relative it stays in the correct cell but is aligned at the top of the cell.

Help please

Comment: when you say cell, do you mean table cell or like bootstraps grid system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know, every .col-* class has position relative property as per bootstrap. !! You just gave one of it position:absolute, so its gonna follow its parent relative element.

inspite that ! let that element be relative, remove all your properties, create a child element inside that column, give it position absolute, and position it right-bottom.

your position:absolute, is simply breaking its structure. thatsy its not falling in proper place.

Comment: Thank you!  I changed it to: <div class="col-md-4 column"> <span style='position:absolute:botom:0;right:0;'>text here</span></div>  And it now shows up in the bottom of the row on top of it.  Sorry I'm such an idiot.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Never mind... We all do some mistakes.. It happens... ! But i would be glad, if you would mark it as answer - if it worked.